# Overriding Defaultkeyboard

Tags: android

I have a cusom view which is programmatically created.I want to show it instead of android default keyboard.for example in the default Messaging app when user goes to compose message default keyboard pop-ups.Is there any way to show the custom view instead of default keyboard.
   Is there any event or action fired up to show tha default keyboard so that i can hide the default & show the custom view.please help.
  thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to show the custom view instead of default keyboard

You are welcome to rework your "custom view" to be [an input method editor](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html). Users can then *choose* to use your input method editor if they wish. You cannot *force* users to use your input method editor.

Comment: I am making my own InputMethodService.Everything is working fine.But I have one issue.I want to make the KeyBoard view transparent.That means the keypad view will cover the enter screen & the user can see the whole screen while typing.
    I tried a lot to make it TRANSPARENT by setting BACKGROUND COLOR,DRAWABLE,but could not success.
   Please suggest me how to make a custom TRANSPARENT Keypad.

Comment: @hitansujena: Since I have no idea, you should ask a new StackOverflow question on this topic.