# How can I have an EditText without Android system keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard

I have an EditText and a custom keyboard (LinearLayout with TextView as keys of the keyboard). I want to write from my custom keyboard and to have a cursor tracking my text. The problem is that the system keyboard is appearing when I click the EditText.

How can I have an EditText with a cursor, working with a built-in keyboard?

Comment: Have you tried to hide the system keyboard?

Comment: Yes, but when I click the EditText it appears.

Comment: [overriding-defaultkeyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684775/overriding-defaultkeyboard) might be helpful?

Comment: No, I want to use my custom "keyboard". Anyways thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable keyboard on EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636635/disable-keyboard-on-edittext) (read carefully whole topic)

Comment: I can't have the cursor in this way. So doesn't work for me :)